# Select based on the result of the first SQL select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a similar question here, but instead of relying on the code to do this I would like SQL to handle what I am trying to find.
I need to first select the latest posted record in "my_table", yes I can use "MAX" than I would like to see if this record is older than 24 hours based on today's date or "current_date". Having issues on how to combine the two.

```
SELECT max(date(date_posted)) FROM my_table
WHERE ("SELECT count( DISTINCT my_id ) AS 'a'
      FROM my_table
      WHERE date_posted > date_sub( current_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY )
)
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: could you provide sample of data and expected result set please?

Comment: I am expecting a "0" if the latest record in the table is newer than 24 hours or a "1" if the newest record in the table is older than 24 hours. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine.

```
SELECT max(date(date_posted)) FROM my_table WHERE DATEDIFF(current_date,date_posted) > 1
```

Comment: This one is giving me this error: "Unknown column 'date_posted' in 'having clause'"

Comment: Now if the newest record in the table is from "2015-10-20" your SQL is returning "2015-10-18".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a derived table. From your comment, looks like you are trying to do:

```
select 
case when max(date(date_posted)) > date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) then 1 else 0 end 
as somecolumn
from my_table
```

Comment: This is returning a "1" on top of the result set, but several other records after that.

Comment: see if the modified version is what you need. Your question is unclear

Comment: I have another question for you, If the latest record in the table was posted on "2015-10-19 00:00:06" shouldn't it return a "0"? Because it is newer than 24 hours "now()", right?

Comment: look to change `1` and `0` part in `case` to suit your need.